# $\mathbb Z$ is not a dense generator in $\mathsf{Ab}$

Tags: category-theory

Why is $\mathbb{Z}$ not a dense generator in $\mathsf{Ab}$, the category of abelian groups? This is exercise 4.8.6 in Borceux's Handbook of Categorical Algebra. There is a hint which says to consider $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$.

My attempt at a solution: We know that if $\mathbb Z$ is a dense generator, then the identity is the left Kan extension of the inclusion $j \colon \mathcal G \longrightarrow \mathsf{Ab}$, where $\mathcal G$ is the full subcategory of $\mathsf{Ab}$ with one object $\mathbb Z$. So to prove $\mathbb Z$ is not a dense generator, we can show that the identity is not a left Kan extension. Let $\Delta_{\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z}\colon \mathsf{Ab} \longrightarrow \mathsf{Ab}$ be the constant functor. We can define a natural transformation $\beta \colon j \longrightarrow \Delta_{\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z} j$, which is just a map $\beta \colon \mathbb Z \longrightarrow \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ by $z \mapsto (0,z)$. If the identity were a left Kan extension, there must exist a natural transformation $\gamma \colon \mathsf{id} \longrightarrow \Delta_{\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z}$ such that $\gamma_j = \beta$. But we must have $\gamma_0 \circ 0 = \gamma_\mathbb Z = \beta$ since $\gamma$ is natural, which is impossible since $\beta$ is not zero.

In the above argument, it doesn't seem important that $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ was used, which makes me a bit suspicious. Have I made a mistake?

Comment: It's not important to use $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ in particular -- it's just "the least complicated object" that does the trick. One way to "explain" why $\mathbb{Z}$ is not dense is that $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},-)$ doesn't "see" the addition operation which is important to the structure of the category $\mathsf{Ab}$. The subcategory $\{\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}\}$ _is_ dense, essentially because it includes the universal sum map $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What is a dense generator?

Comment: Let $G$ be an object of a category $\mathcal C$ and let $\mathcal G$ denote the full subcategory of $\mathcal C$ with one object $G$. If the colimit of the forgetful functor $\Gamma^C \colon \mathcal G/C \longrightarrow \mathcal C$ is just given by $C$ (and structure morphisms just given by the relevant morphisms in $\mathcal G/C$ ) for every object $C$ of $\mathcal C$, then $G$ is a dense generator

Comment: @Mariano Paul's definition is adequate (that's a pun: "adequate" is the original term for this concept!), and the extension to many objects is not hard to guess. But my favorite definition is that a dense generator is a full subcategory $\mathcal G \subseteq \mathcal C$ such that the nerve functor $\mathcal{C} \to [\mathcal{G}^\mathrm{op},\mathsf{Set}]$, $c \mapsto \mathrm{Hom}(-,c)$ is fully faithful. For example a site is dense in its category of sheaves, or free groups are dense in all groups, or the finite ordinals are dense in categories. [nlab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dense+functor)